# PHP type matching

Tags: php

In PHP, can someone explain to me why this resolves to true:

```
'NONE' == 0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because any non-numerical string cast to int will turn into 0.

If you don't want that to happen, use ===, the identical operator.

Read:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: This is just nitpicking, but `is_numeric('16 foo')` is `FALSE`, e.g. a non-numerical string and typecasting it to int will turn it into 16, not 0.

Comment: not in this case :) it's all described at http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Answer (score 4):

Because the string is 0 when evaluated in a number context. [Quoting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number  and the comparison performed numerically.

So [it depends on what the string contains](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Also, see the [chapter on Type Juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [Type Comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in the PHP Manual.

Comment: As described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: so ... NONE is a keyword? Like 'false'? (I'm asking this while reading the chapter)

Comment: @Putr no, its a string. nothing more.

Comment: @Putr Not really. Any string in a boolean context evaluates to true. So `('false' == false)` is false, `('false' == true)` is true.

Comment: @NullUser it's not a boolean context here though, but a numeric one, so `('10' == 10)` and `('0xFF' == 255)` and `('16 foo' == 16)` is all true.